# Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer:

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 455, 30), found shape=(None, 30)

completely new to ML, starting a beginner project, unsure why the shape has changed and what i can do to make the model load. Here is my code for reference.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

df= pd.read_csv (r'/Users/aishwaryaiyer/Desktop/cancer.csv')
print (df)
x = df.drop(columns =["diagnosis(1=m, 0=b)"])
y = df["diagnosis(1=m, 0=b)"]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape= x_train.shape, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation= 'sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation= 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)
```

Comment: We get exactly this question every day, did you search this site about the solution?

Answer (score 0):

your input shape is wrong because you are giving the whole dataset as input shape. It should only be: `input_shape= x_train[1].shape` which is the 30 features you are giving the model. the 455 are the 455 train data points you have but the model only needs to know the feature shape.